# JDBC ResultSet to ArrayList, ArrayList to .txt file

Tags: jdbc

I got the following piece of code that retrieves all rows in a table:

```
        String MakeTXT = "USE SRO_VT_SHARD Select * from _RefTeleLink";
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(MakeTXT);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        ArrayList<String> links = new ArrayList<>();

        int i = 1;
        String rows = "";

        while (rs.next()) {
            for (i = 1; i <= 22; i++) {
                links.add(rs.getString(i));

                if (i == 22) {
                    links.add("\n");
                }
            }
        }
        rows = String.join("\t", links);
        System.out.println(rows);
    }
}
```

What I want to do is:

- Select all rows from the table. See result: prnt.sc/egbh4o
- Write all selected rows to a .txt file
- .txt file has to look something like this (literally copy pasted the rows): http://prntscr.com/egbhn4

What my code currently outputs:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAgyJ.png)

It does this because there are 22 columns, and when the loop reaches 22, it adds an enter to the ArrayList.

What I'm actually looking for is a way to copy an entire row using ResultSet, instead of using a for loop to loop 22 times, and make a row of the 22 results.

Have looked everywhere but couldn't find anything.. :(

Comment: Bad code in many ways.  Magic numbers are never, ever a good idea.  It would be easy to map all the columns by getting meta data about the ResultSet first.   I would consider code that combined a database query without output to a text file to be poorly layered.

Comment: Don't put formatting separators in your list. Create a List of rows, where each row is itself a list of values. Then iterate of the rows to write each of them to the file.

Comment: @JBNizet , I'm trying to find a way to add one row as a whole to a list. Right now what it does is it adds the value of each column to a list like this: http://prntscr.com/egbowp

Each line is supposed to be one row.

Comment: Then do that. As I just said. What is a row in your case? Isn't it a list of values, each of type String? So it's a List<String>, right? So, a list f rows is a List<List<String>>.

Comment: Perhaps try using `System.lineSeparator()` instead of `"\n"` since you are on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need an ArrayList to hold the column values as they are read. I'd better use a StringBuilder as show below, concatenating tabs inside the loop and then replacing the last one with a line feed.

```
    String MakeTXT = "USE SRO_VT_SHARD Select * from _RefTeleLink";
    Statement stm = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(MakeTXT);
    List<String> rows = new ArrayList<>();
    StringBuilder row = new StringBuilder();
    ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
    final int colCount = meta.getColumnCount();
    while (rs.next()) {
        row.setLength(0);
        for (int c=0; c<=colCount; c++)
            row.append(rs.getString(c)).append("\t");
        row.setCharAt(row.length()-1, '\n');
        rows.add(row.toString());
    }       
    rs.close();
    stm.close();
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Added this separator: String.join("", rows); And it prints everything perfectly!!